# Newey West and White correction on Linear Regression in R

Tags: regression, robust

I really need some help

I have to see if there is an effect of holidays, special days, and weather on my daily data. The daily data has clearly a seasonal cycle.

So for this,I am trying to run linear regression with around 1100 observations. The first step was to transformer the number of sells as described in the papers I read.

**Rt=Ln(Pt/Pt-1)*100**

Where Pt is the the sales of today, and Pt-1 from the previous day

To account for the seasonality, I simply have a first linear regression using the day of the week as dummy variable

```
fit<- lm(log_return~D1+D3+D4+D5+D6+D7,data=mydata)
```

which with OLS gives the following result: [Model Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYYdS.jpg)

The residuals are non-normal, Q-Q Plot shows some heavy legs. I think it might be because **the Residuals have significant heteroscedacity and autocorrelation**.

From the papers I read, the **authors always used Standard White and Newey West** for correction of heterscedacity and autocorrelation in the residuals. variables, I have both problem making my OLS certainly wrong.

From the **sandwich** documentation for R, **it appears that Newey West can find automaticly the right amount of lags**, which is for me great, because I tried several ARMA(p,q) variants without success.

So now I run the **vcovHAC(fit)**, I am not really sure what it is. Does it correct my problem of unknown autocorrelation and heteroscedacity by itself completly also with White SE,and find the necessary lag(s) needed to correct the regression?

**How do I apply this then on my regression to get the same summary as summary(fit), but with the corrected values in R, including Rsquared?
Does it magicly correct everything ? What are the limits?**

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help:

- [R and Newey-West](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sandwich/versions/2.4-0/topics/NeweyWest)
- [R and ARMA](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tseries/versions/0.10-42/topics/arma)
- [R and vcovHAC](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sandwich/versions/2.4-0/topics/vcovHAC)
- [R and Linear Regression](http://r-statistics.co/Linear-Regression.html)

Comment: From the first example. It is unclear from me if y will get lagged correction or only x. Is also Neweywest the same as vcovHAC without arguments ? The R squared do not get better, Q-Q plot and ACF of fit stay inchanged despite correction ? Do I have to add lags into the regression, like this     lm(y ~ x + lag1y) ?

    x <- sin(1:100)
    y <- 1 + x + rnorm(100)
    fm <- lm(y ~ x)
    vcovHAC(fm)
    vcov(fm)